# should I use a private field of a widget or a local widget

Tags: java, android, android-studio, field, local

More often than not I will use a private field when using widgets:
`private Button mondayButton;`.
On the other hand Android suggests the usage of local variables: 
`Button mondayButton = findViewById(R.id.monday_button);`. 

What do you recommend and what are the benefits as well as the disadvantages?

Comment: depends on what u need. do u need to access mondayButton on another method?

Comment: in this case I am only using it in onCreate so that is a no

Comment: then just make it local variable

Comment: oh alright thank you

Comment: I tried changing it and it caused an error. I think its because I access the layout widget through Buttons interface onClick method.

Comment: then use [listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button)